# Why does this sum not diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

So I'm asking this question in general but with a motivating example:

Say we have a function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
So both the top ($x^n$) and bottom ($n!$) of this function grow -> infinity as n -> infinity, as long as x > 1. Since this series converges for any value of x given, this implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=0$ for all values of x, which itself implies that the bottom grows faster to infinity than the top.

The reason I'm asking is because it's not intuitive: sure, as n->infinity they both go to infinity, but it makes sense that $x^n$ would go to infinity way faster than n!; it doesn't make sense that the bottom might grow faster than the top, since it seems like normally, for any given a>1, $a^x\to\infty$ way quicker than $x!$. Why does it not diverge? Do the graphs of $f(x)=a^x$ and $f(x)=x!$ ever cross over each other, where x! overtakes the former?

Edit: no, they don't cross over. I checked (see below). What's interesting though is that while the exponential function (red, assuming a = 10) always grows faster to infinity than the factorial function (blue), they maintain (roughly) the same distance (difference in x) between the curves for any given value of y, which might explain something.

Graph I'm referring to:[image: graph from desmos]

But why for any of this?

Comment: **Intuitive explanation :** $x^n = x \times ... \times x$ is the product of $n$ factors which are all constant (equal to $x$) ; whereas $n! = 1 \times 2 \times ... \times n$ is the product of $n$ factors which are bigger and bigger as $n$ is big.

Comment: You could use Stirling equivalent to "understand" that $n!$ is only a little smaller that $n^n$ which is enormous compared to any $x^n$

Comment: They do cross over. Your graph just doesn't go far enough to the right. Specifically, $25!>10^{25}$.

Answer (score 5):

Write
$$
\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x}{1}\cdot\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{x}{3}\cdot\frac{x}{4}\cdots\frac{x}{n} .
$$
Fix $x$.  Once $n$ goes beyond $x$, the factors $\frac{x}{n}$ are ${}< 1$.  When $n$ gets large (compared to $x$) **most** of the factors are ${} < 1$.

---

Another note.  We have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = +\infty
\tag1$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0 .
\tag2$$

The one that matters for this convergence is $(2)$.

---

Take $a=10$.  Then the graphs $10^n$ and $n!$ **do** cross at about $n=25$.  Here we see it by graphing the logarithms of the two functions:

[image: B]

$\log(10^n)$ in red; and $\log(n!)$ in blue.

Answer (score -2):

If you consider that the mass function of a Poisson variable is $$P(\{x\})=e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ and that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(\{x\})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}=1$$ since it's a probability, then you can complete the sum you have the following way:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^{-x}}\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}}_{=1}=\frac{1}{e^{-x}}$$

Thus the sum converges to $$\frac{1}{e^{-x}}$$.

Sometimes it's easier to use probability arguments to explain analysis problems. And it works with all probability distributions, you just have to recognize them :)